# .NET external DLL log redirection

Tags: .net, logging, dll, nlog, console-redirect

The case is this:

- I have a .net application which uses and calls an external win32 dll methods.
- The dll itself does a lot of console logging for debugging purposes

Is there a way to prefetch the logs from the dll when executing its methods and redirect them to a file or so?

I can redirect the app's console output to a file without a problem - but the DLL calls remain hidden (i only see them in the actual console).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whomever this might help, [here is the solution for this](http://gabesworkshop.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/miniws/ConsoleReading/ConsoleRedirector.cs):

> ```
> #region thanks
> /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
> // With thanks to nobugz                                       //
> // MVP, Moderator on the MSDN C# general forums                //
> // http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Profile/en-US/?user=nobugz //
> ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
> #endregion
>
> using System;
> using System.Diagnostics;
> using System.IO;
> using System.IO.Pipes;
> using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
> using System.Text;
> using System.Threading;
>
> namespace miniws
> {
>     internal sealed class ConsoleRedirector : IDisposable
>     {
>         private static ConsoleRedirector _instance;
>
>         public static void attach(ILogListener listener)
>         {
>             Debug.Assert(null == _instance);
>             _instance = new ConsoleRedirector(listener);
>         }
>
>         public static void detatch()
>         {
>             _instance.Dispose();
>             _instance = null;
>         }
>
>         public static bool isAttached
>         {
>             get
>             {
>                 return null != _instance;
>             }
>         }
>
>         //----------------------------------------------------------------------
>
>         private const int PERIOD = 500;
>         private const int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;
>         private volatile bool _isDisposed;
>         private readonly ILogListener _logListener;
>         private readonly IntPtr _stdout;
>         private readonly IntPtr _stderr;
>         private readonly Mutex _sync;
>         private readonly Timer _timer;
>         private readonly char[] _buffer;
>         private readonly AnonymousPipeServerStream _outServer;
>         private readonly AnonymousPipeServerStream _errServer;
>         private readonly TextReader _outClient;
>         private readonly TextReader _errClient;
>
>         // ReSharper disable UseObjectOrCollectionInitializer
>         private ConsoleRedirector(ILogListener logListener)
>         {
>             bool ret;
>             AnonymousPipeClientStream client;
>
>             _logListener = logListener;
>             _stdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
>             _stderr = GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE);
>             _sync = new Mutex();
>             _buffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
>
>             _outServer = new AnonymousPipeServerStream(PipeDirection.Out);
>             client = new AnonymousPipeClientStream(PipeDirection.In,
> _outServer.ClientSafePipeHandle);
>             //client.ReadTimeout = 0;
>             Debug.Assert(_outServer.IsConnected);
>             _outClient = new StreamReader(client, Encoding.Default);
>             ret = SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, _outServer.SafePipeHandle.DangerousGetHandle());
>             Debug.Assert(ret);
>
>             _errServer = new AnonymousPipeServerStream(PipeDirection.Out);
>             client = new AnonymousPipeClientStream(PipeDirection.In,
> _errServer.ClientSafePipeHandle);
>             //client.ReadTimeout = 0;
>             Debug.Assert(_errServer.IsConnected);
>             _errClient = new StreamReader(client, Encoding.Default);
>             ret = SetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE, _errServer.SafePipeHandle.DangerousGetHandle());
>             Debug.Assert(ret);
>
>             Thread outThread = new Thread(doRead);
>             Thread errThread = new Thread(doRead);
>             outThread.Name = "stdout logger";
>             errThread.Name = "stderr logger";
>             outThread.Start(_outClient);
>             errThread.Start(_errClient);
>             _timer = new Timer(flush, null, PERIOD, PERIOD);
>         }
>         // ReSharper restore UseObjectOrCollectionInitializer
>
>         private void flush(object state)
>         {
>             _outServer.Flush();
>             _errServer.Flush();
>         }
>
>         private void doRead(object clientObj)
>         {
>             TextReader client = (TextReader)clientObj;
>             try
>             {
>                 while (true)
>                 {
>                     int read = client.Read(_buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
>                     if (read > 0)
>                         //Console.WriteLine(" log :"+_buffer.ToString()+read);
>                         _logListener.writeChars(_buffer, 0, read);
>                 }
>             }
>             catch (ObjectDisposedException)
>             {
>                 // Pipe was closed... terminate
>             }
>         }
>
>         public void Dispose()
>         {
>             Dispose(true);
>         }
>
>         ~ConsoleRedirector()
>         {
>             Dispose(false);
>         }
>
>         // ReSharper disable InconsistentNaming
>         // ReSharper disable UnusedParameter.Local
>         // ReSharper disable EmptyGeneralCatchClause
>         private void Dispose(bool disposing)
>         {
>             if (!_isDisposed)
>             {
>                 lock (_sync)
>                 {
>                     if (!_isDisposed)
>                     {
>                         _isDisposed = true;
>                         _timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
>                         _timer.Dispose();
>                         flush(null);
>
>                         try { SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, _stdout); }
>                         catch (Exception) { }
>                         _outClient.Dispose();
>                         _outServer.Dispose();
>
>                         try { SetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE, _stderr); }
>                         catch (Exception) { }
>                         _errClient.Dispose();
>                         _errServer.Dispose();
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>         // ReSharper restore EmptyGeneralCatchClause
>         // ReSharper restore UnusedParameter.Local
>         // ReSharper restore InconsistentNaming
>
>         // ReSharper disable InconsistentNaming
>         private const int STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11;
>         private const int STD_ERROR_HANDLE = -12;
>
>         [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
>         [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
>         private static extern bool SetStdHandle(int nStdHandle, IntPtr hHandle);
>
>         [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
>         private static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);
>         // ReSharper restore InconsistentNaming
>     }
>
>
> }
> ```

Comment: In case you are looking for the current source code the repo has been moved to github: https://github.com/neolode/gabesworkshop/blob/master/miniws/ConsoleReading